# User Tracking in Liferay Community Edition

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Like we have an User Tracking inbuilt facility in liferay do we have any thing with such functionalities in community edition.

Can you suggest any third party open source tool or plugin with user tracking functionalities.

help me regarding this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up by implementing my own code. rather than using liferay inbuild functionality.
1.Here is the Jsp code for my file.

```
    //Page Imports & taglibs
    <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.UserTrackerPathUtil"%>
    <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil"%>
    <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.UserTrackerPathLocalServiceUtil"%>
    <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.UserTrackerLocalServiceUtil"%>
    <%@page import="com.liferay.counter.service.CounterLocalServiceUtil" %>
    <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil" %>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.UserTracker" %>
    <%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.UserTrackerPath" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="theme"%>
    <%-- <%@include file="/html/demo/one.jsp" %> --%>

    <theme:defineObjects/>
    // Define theme object to get user and other basic information
    <%
    HttpSession http_session = request.getSession();
    //Get the current session variable.

     String id = http_session.getId();
    //Getting id of session
         String path = themeDisplay.getLayout().getFriendlyURL();
    //Getting path that will be stored in path field of UserTrackerPath table.
        System.out.println("***==> Current Url => "+ themeDisplay.getURLCurrent());
    //path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"));
    String localhostname = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        //Getting the localhost name of machine from which user is acccessing site
    String ipAddress  = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        //Getting ip address of machine, In case of if user is using an proxy env you may need some other efforts to get exact ip. 
       if(ipAddress == null)  
       {  
          ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
       }  
    try {
            UserTracker user_tracker =     (UserTracker)http_session.getAttribute("user_tracker");
    //Now when user session creates for first time then you need to add an entry in UserTracker table and all the rest entries for path traversal are need to be added at UserTrackerPath with new userTrackerPathId and userTrackerId as foreignkey.
            if(user_tracker == null) 
            {
                    UserTracker tracker = null;
                    ArrayList<UserTrackerPath> userTrackerPath = new ArrayList<UserTrackerPath>();
    //Create an Array List of UserTrackerPath needs to be added in method of addUserTracker by UserTrackerLocalServiceUtil
                    UserTrackerPath utp= null;
                    utp = UserTrackerPathLocalServiceUtil.createUserTrackerPath(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());

                    utp.setPath(path);
                    utp.setPathDate(new java.util.Date());
                    userTrackerPath.add(utp);
    //Add an entry to array list                
            tracker = UserTrackerLocalServiceUtil.addUserTracker(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(),
                            themeDisplay.getUserId(),
                            new java.util.Date(),
                            id,
                            ipAddress,
                            localhostname,
                            userAgent,
                            userTrackerPath);
    //UserTracker will be added to database
                    http_session.setAttribute("user_tracker",tracker);
       //Adds value to session to check that next time session is null or not, so that it can decide whether to execute code of if or else.
            }
            else
            {
    //If session is not null then you already have an entry in UserTracker and you need to keep path track in UserTarckerPath Table
                UserTrackerPath utp  = UserTrackerPathLocalServiceUtil.createUserTrackerPath(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());
                utp.setUserTrackerId(user_tracker.getUserTrackerId());
                utp.setPath(path);
                utp.setPathDate(new java.util.Date());
                utp =     UserTrackerPathLocalServiceUtil.updateUserTrackerPath(utp, true);
    //Update path 
            }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    %>
```

2. So now go to your `portal-ext.properties` and add following properties

   ```
   session.tracker.persistence.enabled=true

   live.users.enabled=false

   session.tracker.ignore.paths=\/portal/render_portlet,\/document_library/get_file
   ```
3. Once done include Jsp to your theme `portal-normal.vm` so that it gets accesible every where.have a look into
   [Add a global Jsp to include in Liferay tomcat-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728100/add-a-global-jsp-to-include-in-liferay-tomcat-6)
   and it will add tracked data to table successfully. :)

Note: If there is any alternative to this in CE will be glad to receive you suggestions on this.
Thanks :)