# Add a global Jsp to include in Liferay tomcat-6

Tags: liferay, tomcat6

I have a Jsp that dynamically needs to get included in entire project as user opens any jsp. i.e. As a user opens a jsp my jsp should automatically gets included.

I have written this in web.xml in Tomcat

```
<jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>/webapps/ROOT/html/*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
        <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
        <is-xml>false</is-xml>
        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/tracker.jsp</include-prelude>
        <!-- <include-coda>/template/coda.jspf</include-coda> -->
</jsp-property-group>
```

I had kept my jsp in tomcat under WEB-INF/jsp/ and i want to include it into every porject as it contains a code that tracks log for user.

Or any other way to make this happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for this.

Simple way is to include your JSP in the Theme. When your Theme is applied to your project, and when Theme is rendered, any pages in your project will render this included JSP.

Code sample below. This has to be placed in vm file(navigation.vm).

`$theme.include($themeServletContext, "/jsp/yourJSPPageToBeIncluded.jsp")`

Here, JSP folder is placed directly inside Theme war.

Other way (tedious one), is to include this JSP in each and every JSP page that you want this to be included.

Use `<jsp:include>` element for this.

Some references,

[Ref1](http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo330/2s03/projects/Tomcat/doc/1.2/syntaxref1214.html)
[Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file)

Comment: can we do it making its entry in tomcat web.xml. Is that possible. I tired it worked for first time. But then no-more. Cz in case if we are using Multiple themes i guess there might be a problem.

Comment: Not sure if this can be done through web.xml file of Tomcat.. I really doubt that..

Comment: Vikas i did it with tomcat it worked fine for first time, but unluckily it only worked out for 1st time and no more :(. I guess there is a solution its just we need to seek it. :) any ways 'l let you know if i get any thing. Vice-Versa

Answer (score 4):

There is one more way to include your JSP for the whole portal and i.e. the dockbar.

You can create a hook and include your jsp in the `/html/portlet/dockbar/view.jsp` using either `<jsp:include />` or `<liferay-util:include />` or simple `<%@ include file="" />` (this would be static).

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/yourJSPPageToBeIncluded.jsp" />
```

OR

```
<liferay-util:include page="/jsp/yourJSPPageToBeIncluded.jsp" />
```

OR

```
<%@ include file="/jsp/yourJSPPageToBeIncluded.jsp" />
```

Note: the path may differ depending on where you will be putting the JSP.

Why I am choosing dockbar is because it is present on all the portal-pages of liferay. This won't work if you are opening a pop-up like configuration pop-up or look-and-feel pop-up or other custom dialog pop-ups since dockbar is not present in the pop-up. For using in pop-ups you would have to override `portal_pop_up.vm` in your custom-theme and write the code as suggested by @VikasV

```
$theme.include($themeServletContext, "/jsp/yourJSPPageToBeIncluded.jsp")
```

Comment: Thanks for post I got it done using     $theme.include($themeServletContext, "/jsp/yourJSPPageToBeIncluded.jsp") the only thing i included is portal-impl.jar. But since this adds an dependency to my code. I want an independent solution. can i use web.xml of tomcat. I did used it it worked for first time. but then no changes were reflected. Any expertise on this matter. please share it. Regarding Tomcat

Comment: `portal-impl.jar` is not recommended to be added to any of the plugins and starting from Liferay 6.1 it is prohibited. Will look for an alternate solution with `web.xml` and update you